# Pushing a UIViewController from a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I  need to push a `UIView` into my `UINavigation controller`. I am doing it by

```
[self.view addSubview:showContactFlow];
```

And on a button click in UIView I need to push another UIViewController over the `UIView`. From the `UIView` I am not able to access `self.navigationcontroller` How can I do this?

Edit:

I have set the `UIView` as the view of a new `UIViewController` I am pushing into, the before mentioned `UIViewController` . Now I would like to know, how to handle the `UIView` button event inside its `UIViewController`, in which's view it is set.

Comment: This is not the properly way for doing it, view and view controllers are different kind of object. View Controllers do have a kind of hierarchies that uiviews don't. You can't actually push a navigation controller from a normal view controller (well in ios5 you can do it, but is not logically correct). You need to create a uinavigationcontroller with inside the view controller that you want to display and then display it modally. If you just want to simulate the behavior of push animation you can simply do by using core animation or just uiview's animations.

Comment: Ok. I get it. I just want to know, how can I handle `UIView's` button event from its parent `UIViewController`.

Comment: Xavi could you try to explain better the question, 'cause I'm not getting how you set up the application. Because for me push means the action of `[self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:YES]`. I'm not getting it, sorry

Comment: My primary problem was that I had a class that subclassed `UIView` and I had to have that `UIView` in my `UINavigationController`. And I have to load another `UIViewController` from the 'UIView'.
Going by your advice, I created a new `UIViewController` without a xib and added 'UIView` as the view of the new `UIViewController`. 

I have a custom `UIView` inside the before mentioned 'UIView`. Now the problem I am having is that I need to handle the events of the new 'UIView` inside my `UIViewController` which holds the parent 'UIView` which holds the current 'UIView'.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UINavigationController` ivar to the `UIView` and assign it to the main view controller's. Then you should be able to access it from the `UIView`.

Edit:

Your UIView subclass:

```
// CustomView.h
@interface CustomView: UIView {
    // ...
    // your variables
    // ...
    UINavigationController *navController;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UINavigationController *navController; // assign, because this class is not the owner of the controller

// custom methods

@end

// CustomView.m
@implementation Customview

// synthesize other properties
@synthesize navController;

// implementation of custom methods

// don't release the navigation controller in the dealloc method, your class doesn't own it

@end
```

Then before the `[self.view addSubview:showContactFlow];` line just add `[showContactFlow setNavController:[self navigationController]];` and then you should be able to access your hierarchy's navigation controller from your `UIView` and use it to push other `UIViewController`s.

Comment: Add a `UINavigationController` member to your `UIView` class and assign it to the view controller's navigation controller before adding the view as a subview. Then you will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to work with an MVC approach. So your controller has access to all that stuff and can keep pushing and popping views, so the view doesn't need to know too much about the controller.

Otherwise, and for this case you can solve it fast by using **delegation**. So:

```
showContactFlow.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:showContactFlow];
```

So later in the `UIView`, you can just say:

```
[self.delegate addSubview:self];
```

This is gonna work, but it's not likely to be the best approach you should use.

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you can present a view controller like,

```
    -(void)buttonFunction{
           ThirdVC *third= [[ThirdVC alloc]initWithNibNme];......

           [self presentViewController:third animated:NO];


    }
```

Using Core animation you can make NavigationController's pushviewController like animation on writing code in ThirdVC's viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: self doesn't find a method called `presentViewController`

Answer (score 0):

where do you add the UIButton is it in showContactFlow view or in the ViewController's view??

In regard to the modalViewControllers issue the correct method is

```
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

the standard animation in upwards